# Add image to tooltip in zurb foundation

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation

Hi Im creating a checkout form, and I want to add a tooltip for show where to find the CVV of the credit card.

So if the people hover the tooltip then in the popup show an image, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can add HTML to the `title` tag. You can add an `<img>` tag like this:

```
<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="<img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'> Tooltips are awesome, you should totally use them!">extended information</span>
```

[image]

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/L6u7jyvm/).

Comment: this seems not to work with foundation 6.2, it return the code instead of rendering the img in the tooltip.

Comment: I had to follow this [PR](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/8075/commits/ae2129f859f0ea49392c0dc5a5d5db87c179761d) to get html working in F6 tooltips (be careful to make sure that only trusted code will be in the tooltips to avoid injection issues - see [this thread](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/38057-tooltip-foundation-6-does-not-accept-html-tags)